# Two-ways random effects with unbalanced panel data in R

Tags: r, random-effects-model, fixed-effects-model, hausman

I am currently working with a panel data set in R. So far I specified a fixed effects model with two fixed effects (company/individual and time). Now I want to justify my choice by performing Hausman tests. Thus, I need to estimate a random effects model with the same two unobserved effects. I am using the plm-package to fit my models. Unfortunately, the two-ways random effects model is not implemented for unbalanced panel data in the plm-package.

Does anybody know another way to fit such a model in R? Optimally, it should be compatible with the plm-package, so that I can use it in the plm Hausman-test function.

Any help would be very much appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: Two-way unbalanced RE models will be in the next release of `plm`. You can try the development version, if you dare.

Comment: Thank you @Helix123! Do you know when this update will be released? And how can I run the development version?